# Top 2 finding highst salary is not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here i am trying to take top 2  highest salary in my table. i am trying mysql but it is throwing error.

My Table

```
 CREATE TABLE `employees` (
 `empId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `firstName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
 `lastName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
 `gender` enum('Male','Female') COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
 `salary` double NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`empId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin
```

SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 `salary` FROM `employees` ORDER BY `salary` DESC
```

ERROR

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2 `salary` FROM `employees` ORDER BY `salary` DESC

Comment: Hint:  `LIMIT 2`.  Don't use SQL Server syntax in MySQL.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff,My main question is i have to find N th salary,using your query how we can achive

Comment: "My main question is i have to find N th salary" No that isn't the question in this question.. the question title is "Top 2 finding highst salary is not working in mysql" and a the text "Here i am trying to take top 2 highest salary in my table" @KumaresanM

Answer (score 1):

Not all database systems support the SELECT TOP clause.
In your case you can use

```
SELECT * FROM `employees` ORDER BY `salary` DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: My main question is i have to find `N` th salary,using your query how we can achive

Comment: "My main question is i have to find N th salary" No that isn't the question in this question.. the question title is "Top 2 finding highst salary is not working in mysql" and a the text "Here i am trying to take top 2 highest salary in my table" @KumaresanM

Answer (score 0):

> My main question is i have to find N th salary,using your query how we
>   can achive

One and i think the best option is to use MySQL's user variables.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (
    SELECT 
     *
     , (@rank := @rank + 1 ) AS rank
    FROM 
     employees
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rank := 0 ) AS init_user_var
    ORDER BY 
     employees.salary DESC
)
 AS employees_salary_ranked
WHERE 
 employees_salary_ranked.rank = [number]
```

Comment: It is working fine but i am feeling like this is difficult,apart from this simply how we achive

Comment: "It is working fine but i am feeling like this is difficult,apart from this simply how we achive" this is one off the most eazy approach @KumaresanM the co-related sub query with count approach is much hard to understand and it's performance is also bad.

Answer (score 0):

to find nth highest salary-

```
SELECT salary FROM Employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT N-1, 1
```

Comment: I tried `SELECT salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2-1, 1` your code but i am getting error

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1, 1' at line 1

Comment: n-1 is logical,you have to take a variable and capture the value of n-1 into it